# Formal Proof Using propositional logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I got about making a formal proof for this using propositional logic?

$A$$=$$(A^C)^C$

Comment: Is $A\in\mathcal{M}(\Bbb{R})_{n\times n}$?

Comment: Is $A$ a set?  $\quad x\in(A^C)^C\iff x\not\in A^C\iff x\in A$

Comment: Yes sorry for not clarifying. A is a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the complement is taken with respect to some set $X$, that is, assuming that $A\subset X$ and $A^c = X\setminus A$; then $A^c$ is the *unique* subset of $X$ such that
$$A\cap A^c = \varnothing \quad \textrm{and} \quad A\cup A^c = X.$$
So, $(A^c)^c$ is the **only** subset such that (just replace $A$ with $A^c$ in the latter definition)
$$A^c\cap (A^c)^c = \varnothing \quad \textrm{and} \quad A^c\cup (A^c)^c = X,$$
and, comparing the preceding one, we observe that $(A^c)^c$ must be the same as $A$.